# Java. Как прочитать из xml файла значение одного из параметров?

Tags: java, строки

Здравствуйте, у меня в `xml` файле данные в формате:

```
<AddOrder book="book-3" operation="SELL" price="100.80" volume="24" orderId="149" />
<AddOrder book="book-3" operation="BUY" price="100.20" volume="42" orderId="151" />
```

При чтении файла(по строкам методом `readLine()`) я загружаю все данные из него в `HashMap`, и в качестве ключа у меня выступает параметр `orderId` то есть само значение - цифра которая стоит в кавычках.

Подскажите как мне цивилизованным методом ее от туда вытащить? Понятно что я могу придумать какое-нибудь извращение на подобии рассплитить строку в массив и ковыряться в ней при помощи пачки условных операторов, но хочется сделать по человечески. Наверняка для такой типовой задачи, есть нормальное API.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Для работы с XML есть два разных типа parser:

- SAX ([SAXParser](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/javax/xml/parsers/SAXParser.html)) - основан на событиях
- DOM ([Document](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/org/w3c/dom/Document.html)) - основан на древовидной модели документа

Если у вас есть Schema вашего документа или вы готовы ее создать самостоятельно, то вы можете воспользоваться фреймворком [JAXB](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/articles/javase/index-140168.html) ([руководство](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/jaxb/intro/)). Используя его вы получить дерево, где в качестве узлов будут Java-объекты принадлежащие классам, имена которых будут соответствовать узлам вашего XML. В вашем случае у вас будет класс `AddOrder`.

Comment: извиняюсь забыл у меня условие задачи что можно испольовать Java SE а этот  JAXB он к нему не относится?

Comment: @Павел JAXB входит в состав SE. пакет [javax.xml.bind](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/javax/xml/bind/package-summary.html)

Comment: Вот почему несчастному смартфону, который толком-то ничего и не делает, нужны гигабайты памяти.